# Not able to pass variable through extends in Laravel blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I am trying to pass a variable as below:

**Controller**:

```
public function index()
    {

        $data = [....];

        return view('front.package.searchForm', ['data' => $data]);

    }
```

**front/package/searchForm.blade.php** :

```
@extends('layouts.front.frame', ['var' => 'Value'])
```

In layouts/front/frame.blade.php trying to print variable $var which is passed above file.

**layouts/front/frame.blade.php** :

```
{{ $var }}
```

The above code throwing below error:

***Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException***

***Undefined variable: var (View: ......)***

Is there anything wrong in above code?

I am Using:

PHP : 7.2

Laravel : 5.8.35

Comment: use laravel view composer to send data to specific view https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/views

Comment: Having the same issue after upgrading fro 5.8 to 7.2. Have you figured out what was wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Just Do this

```
@php
$var="Value" 
@endphp
```

```
{{$var}}
```